# How do I randomly select from a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, random, import

Basically, I've got a homework task of programming a text based battle simulator in Python. Obviously I've gone with pokémon...
I would like the enemy to be randomly selected, however I don't know how to randomly select from a list...

```
    foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    from random import choice
    print choice(foo)
```

This is what I've been told to try but I've got no modules or anything imported...
How can I make this work,
appreciated.

Comment: What exactly does not work in the code snippet? What is the error message?

Comment: That should work fine.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the above code.  Are you unclear on how imports work or something?

Comment: I am yes, I have not used imports before.

Comment: The error message is just invalid syntax highlighting 'choice'

Comment: Python 2 or 3? If 3, it should be `print(choice(foo))`.

Comment: Thank you, I literally forgot the brackets...

Comment: @LiamBlock: Made my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Python 3, `print` should be used as a function:

```
print(choice(foo));
```

Answer (score 2):

That code should work. The only reason it might not work would be that you have a file named `random.py` in the same directory as your script.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution  should work. You can use this for testing :

```
from random import choice
foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
for i in range(10):
    print choice(foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

it is very easy.

import random

foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

print foo[random.randint(0,len(foo))]